# MongoDB GridFS Get ID of a file

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-4, gridfs

I am using MongoDB GridFS to store user avatars. I am using Laravel 4.2.

I am writing a function to clean up the DB of any unused avatars; *an avatar is unused if it's id is not associated with any user (User model)*. Given the ID of an avatar I can remove the file from the DB. However I am having trouble extracting ID's of an avatar so I can compare it with those in the `User` model.

The data looks like this:

```
    $avatars = DB::collection('user_avatars.files')->get();
    return Response::json( $avatars[0] );

    //result:
    {"_id":{"$id":"542797096a8d09ac318b456b"},"extension":"jpg","usage":0,"popularity":[],"filename":"image.jpg","uploadDate":{"sec":1411880713,"usec":671000},"length":248388,"chunkSize":262144,"md5":"2c724361015c7e438d30359dd9c724a0"}
```

Now if I write:

```
    return Response::json( $avatars[0]['_id'] );

    //result is:
    {"$id":"542797096a8d09ac318b456b"}
```

How would I grab `542797096a8d09ac318b456b`? Anything I have tried so far does not give the ID but throws an error:

```
$avatars[0]['_id']->$id;
$avatars[0]['_id']['$id'];
$avatars[0]['_id']->$$id;
$avatars[0]['_id']->{$id};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and it works great:

```
 avatars[0]['_id']->{'$id'};
```

Here is the complete function:

```
public function doPurgeDB()
{
    $removed = array();
    $avatars = DB::collection('user_avatars.files')->get();
    foreach( $avatars as $avatar )
    {
        $avatar_id = $avatar['_id']->{'$id'}; //<<<<=========
        $user = User::where('avatar_id', '=', $avatar_id);
        if( !$user->count() )
        {
            $removed[] = $avatar;
            $this->removeAvatar( $avatar_id );
        }
    }
    return Response::json( $removed );
}

public function removeAvatar( $id )
{
    $grid = DB::getGridFS('user_avatars');
    return $grid->delete( new MongoId( $id ) );
}
```

Comment: While [one line answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266954/one-line-answers) are acceptable, they often result in the answer being routed to the Review Queue (*q.v.*). In addition, sometimes they are not well received by the community. Its usually a good idea to provide a brief explanation.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Yet there are questions that are so specific that they call for `one-line answers`; providing more that one line for such questions would be counter productive. If I had some explanation as to why this answer worked I would include it ... in fact I'll take it upon myself to find out, as it may undoubtedly help others, but I am glad I have a solution and I can continue working on my project.

Answer (score 0):

Cast it to string: `(string)$avatars[0]['_id'];`

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer @chianh. I believe that would work.